# Programming language for web application where 2 views affect each other

Tags: view, project, adventure

I'm planning on building something alike a Choose Your Own Adventure book, pretty simple, with some images, text, counters, and stuff. The catch is that you should be should be able to read what is on the webpage (View 1), but another person entering to another page view (View 2) should be able to get the same information that appears in View 1, as well as some additional information. Additionally, only the person with View 2 should be able to take decisions, changing the text and information being show both for View 1 and View 2.

In the future, I would like it to be able to create a room in the page where someone enters in View 1, another in View 2, and people from other rooms don't affect anything from Views 1 and 2.

I was thinking this was simple enough to code with React, leaving all the room stuff to be done in the future with NodeJS. However, as you are using two views in which one affects the other, I was beginning to think React might not be the best choice, as it is not a single page app. Maybe Python and Django might be better?

Which programming languages would you choose or believe to be better for this sort of project?